# Yammer REST Javascript API

Tags: javascript, html, rest, office365, yammer

I'm trying to include some posts in a page in SharePoint from Yammer. I've found a article on: [http://mosshowto.blogspot.nl/](http://mosshowto.blogspot.nl/2015/10/programmatically-embed-yammer.html)

The code of the solution is on [Github](https://github.com/MarcCharmois/Embed-Yammer-into-SharePoint-Online) and I've added the changes addressed in the article. The page hangs on the status Loading....

The code of the page is below, I've only changed the markup and the tabs.

What can I change to make the page work? It would be great to include the Yammer feeds but on our school we only want a profile image followed by the post. I hope this script should be capable of doing this.

The code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <style>
        .message-list-item-body-message{
        font-size:13px;
        /*line-height:1.3;*/
        color :#343a41;
        font-family : "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- replace the data-app-id value by the Client ID of your Yammer App-->
    <script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="4oZKxfuB2HwVoWOMWT3DA" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var userName="";
        var userPicUrl="";
        var messageTime ="";

        function getMyFeed(origin){
            var myFeed="6636029";
            <!-- replace the following image link with yours -->
            document.getElementById("yammer-feed").innerHTML="<img src='/sites/intranet/Images1/ajax-loader1.gif' style='margin-top:100px;margin-left:95px;' />";
            var tokenToSend = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem(1);
            console.log("origine : " + origin);

            yam.platform.request(
                { 
                    url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/6636029.json" //replace the group ID with yours
                    ,method: "GET"
                    ,beforeSend: function (xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', tokenToSend)}
                    ,success: function (data) { //print message response information to the console

                        try{
                            console.log('data received');
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.messages.length; i++) {
                                groupId = parseInt(data.messages[i].group_id);
                                userId = parseInt(data.messages[i].sender_id); 
                                var post = data.messages[i];
                                for (var j = 0; j < data.references.length; j++) {
                                    if(data.references[j].id==post.sender_id){
                                        userName=data.references[j].full_name;
                                        userPicUrl=data.references[j].mugshot_url;              
                                    }           
                                }
                                postBody=data.messages[i].body.plain;
                                messageTime = data.messages[i].created_at.substring(0,19);
                                myFeed+= "<br><img style='margin-right:3px;float:left;' src='"+ userPicUrl +"'/><div style='color:rgba(0, 138, 94, 1);font-weight:bold;' >" + userName + "<br><br><span style='font-weight:normal;color:silver'>"+ messageTime +"</span></div><div style='clear:both'></div><br>" +  postBody + "<br>";
                                userName="";
                            }

                            myFeed+= "<br><br>";
                            document.getElementById("yammer-feed").innerHTML = myFeed;
                        }

                        catch(error){
                            alert("error getMyFeed process : " + error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (msg) { alert("error getMyFeed ajax : " + msg.value); }
                }
            )
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', function (resp) {
            if (resp.authResponse) {
                //you need the following lines if, when the user refreshes the page he has to log again...
                //you will have to provide the getMyFeed fucntion with the token for authentication
                //localStorage.setItem(1, JSON.stringify(resp.access_token.token).replace(/"/g, ""));
                //console.log("token" + localStorage.getItem(1));

                //Disabled - document.getElementById('yammer-login').style.display = 'none';
                //Disabled - getMyFeed("login");

                localStorage.setItem(1, JSON.stringify(resp.access_token.token).replace(/"/g, ""));
                console.log("token" + localStorage.getItem(1));
                //Hiding the login button because the user is logged in
                document.getElementById('yammer-login').style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div style="border : solid 1px silver;border-bottom: 0px;width:254px;margin-top:11px;">
        <!-- replace the following images links with yours -->
        <img src='/sites/intranet/Images1/Yammer-SharePoint-medium.png' style='width:40px;margin: 0px 15px 0px 5px;float:left'/><div style='width:140px;float:left;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;padding-top:15px;border-left:solid 0px silver;color:rgba(57, 107, 153, 1);font-size:14px;'>Custom Yam Feed</div>
        <a onclick="getMyFeed('refresh');" href="javascript:;" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="/sites/intranet/Images1/refresh%20icon.jpg" style="width:25px;margin: 5px 10px 0px 0px;border-style: none"   /></a>
        <div style='clear:both'></div>
    </div>
    <div id="webService-feed" style="height500px;width:248px;border : solid 1px silver;border-top:0px;margin-top:0px;padding:3px;overflow: scroll;">
        <span class='message-list-item--body-message' id="yammer-feed">
            <span style="margin:3px 0px 3px 1px" id="yammer-login"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Edit 1: 
The HTML

```
<div style="border : solid 1px silver;border-bottom: 0px;width:254px;margin-top:11px;">
<img src="sites/Schoolplein/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/Iconen/yam-small.png" style="width:40px; margin:0px 15px 0px 5px; float:left" />
<div style="width:140px;float:left;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;padding-top:15px;border-left:solid 0px silver;color:rgba(57, 107, 153, 1);font-size:14px;">Nieuwsberichten:</div>
<a onclick="getMyFeed('refresh');" href="javascript:;" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="/sites/Schoolplein/Gedeelde%20%20documenten/Iconen/Refresh.png" style="width:25px;margin: 5px 10px 0px 0px;border-style: none"   /></a>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

#### The code that was included in a script editor

```
<style>
    .message-list-item-body-message{
    font-size:13px;
    /*line-height:1.3;*/
    color :#343a41;
    font-family : "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<!-- replace the data-app-id value by the Client ID of your Yammer App-->
<script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var userName="";
    var userPicUrl="";
    var messageTime ="";

    function getMyFeed(origin){
        var myFeed="6636029";
        <!-- replace the following image link with yours -->
        document.getElementById("yammer-feed").innerHTML="<img src='/sites/intranet/Images1/ajax-loader1.gif' style='margin-top:100px;margin-left:95px;' />";
        var tokenToSend = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem(1);
        console.log("origine : " + origin);

        yam.platform.request(
            { 
                url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/6636029.json" //replace the group ID with yours
                ,method: "GET"
                ,beforeSend: function (xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', tokenToSend)}
                ,success: function (data) { //print message response information to the console

                    try{
                        console.log('data received');
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.messages.length; i++) {
                            groupId = parseInt(data.messages[i].group_id);
                            userId = parseInt(data.messages[i].sender_id); 
                            var post = data.messages[i];
                            for (var j = 0; j < data.references.length; j++) {
                                if(data.references[j].id==post.sender_id){
                                    userName=data.references[j].full_name;
                                    userPicUrl=data.references[j].mugshot_url;              
                                }           
                            }
                            postBody=data.messages[i].body.plain;
                            messageTime = data.messages[i].created_at.substring(0,19);
                            myFeed+= "<br><img style='margin-right:3px;float:left;' src='"+ userPicUrl +"'/><div style='color:rgba(0, 138, 94, 1);font-weight:bold;' >" + userName + "<br><br><span style='font-weight:normal;color:silver'>"+ messageTime +"</span></div><div style='clear:both'></div><br>" +  postBody + "<br>";
                            userName="";
                        }

                        myFeed+= "<br><br>";
                        document.getElementById("yammer-feed").innerHTML = myFeed;
                    }

                    catch(error){
                        alert("error getMyFeed process : " + error);
                    }
                },
                error: function (msg) { alert("error getMyFeed ajax : " + msg.value); }
            }
        )
    }
</script>
<script>
    yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', function (resp) {
        if (resp.authResponse) {
            //you need the following lines if, when the user refreshes the page he has to log again...
            //you will have to provide the getMyFeed fucntion with the token for authentication
            //localStorage.setItem(1, JSON.stringify(resp.access_token.token).replace(/"/g, ""));
            //console.log("token" + localStorage.getItem(1));

            //Disabled - document.getElementById('yammer-login').style.display = 'none';
            //Disabled - getMyFeed("login");

            localStorage.setItem(1, JSON.stringify(resp.access_token.token).replace(/"/g, ""));
            console.log("token" + localStorage.getItem(1));
            //Hiding the login button because the user is logged in
            document.getElementById('yammer-login').style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to register an App in Yammer. During the registration you have to pass to Yammer the domain what will request the Yammer web services. In return Yammer gives you back an Id that you have to pass in your code.

After that, regarding the code, You have to change several things in order the code works:

1 - replace the data-app-id value in the <script> that loads the Yammer SDK with the ID provided by Yammer when registering the App.

2 - replace the group ID in the url of the Yammer request : https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/6636029.json"

After that it should work...

Comment: Hi Marc, I've edited the snippet so that it contains the appid of the app I created. I created the app with the correct domain of https://domain.sharepoint.com. You can see the edited code in my start post, I added a Edit 1 region. The CSS and JavaScript were added in a scripteditor webpart and I've added the HTML through the Embed command. When I save the page and click Login with Yammer, a popup comes up and immediately closes. the page doesn't change afterwards to a frame with the yammer posts.

Comment: Hi Paul, I think it is a trouble with your Browser. It doesn't work with IE9 and with IE latest version you sometimes have to change settings in order it works... Did you try with Chrome and FF ? Did you empty the cache of your browsers ? Good luck...